# Flutter flow screen resolution issue

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I have shared a preview link with my friend and he is not able to see the project updates.
[image].

I have tried to find the solution but it seems not working, and I expect a solution that enable my friend to see the project.

Comment: it seems flutterflow working only on wide screen, try to open it from desktop or laptop